# How do I start an EC2 instance using the latest version of the NodeJS AWS SDK?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, discord.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am trying to make a simple Discord bot in Discord.JS that turns on an EC2 instance when a command is run. I've gotten most of it to work, but I cannot seem to get past this one part of code. I've noticed that it keeps on telling me that I don't have permissions to start an EC2 instance even though it's running on the root user (bad security I know, I'm planning to move it soon) which is written in the code (taken from the docs), but I'm not sure what could be causing me to not have the permissions.

Here is the code I am working with

```
        if (message.content === ">start") {
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region
            AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create EC2 service object
            var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({apiVersion: '2016-11-15'});

            var params = {
                InstanceIds: "i-0c5de602d730d1d24",
                DryRun: true
            };
         // Call EC2 to start the selected instances
                ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err && err.code === 'DryRunOperation') {
                        params.DryRun = false;
                        ec2.startInstances(params, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log("Error", err);
                            } else if (data) {
                                console.log("Success", data.StartingInstances);
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("You don't have permission to start instances.");
                    }
                });
            }
});
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

Thanks for reading and I hope that I can learn from this so that I don't have similar issues in the future!

Comment: Is your account part of AWS Organization? The master account can deny permissions on member accounts even for their roots.

Comment: Try to generate a root access key  at the IAM dashboard and use that

Comment: @AvivLo The key generated is a root access key.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, it is. It is the root account of the entire organization.

Comment: Oh, so SCP does not apply there. Have you tried without Dry Run? This way you may get full error message which specifically says what permissions are denied.

Comment: @Marcin I just did, I still get the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
InstanceIds: ["i-0c5de602d730d1d24"],
```

Comment: No, there is not. It just jumps to the line ```console.log("You don't have permission to start instances.");```

Comment: I changed some code and just got the error  ```InvalidParameterType: Expected params.InstanceIds to be an Array```.

Comment: It's saying permission denied because you log it that way. The real reason as your 2nd comment is that the instanceIds to be an array which is not at the moment. Why down vote my answer, I'm just trying to help.